# reading text file using file channel return illegal characters

Tags: java, file

I'm trying out using file channel to read a large xml file, and here the sample code I found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/UsingFileChanneltoreadtextfile.htm). When I try it out, it's printing out unrecognizable characters:
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File aFile = new File("charData.xml");
    FileInputStream inFile = null;

    inFile = new FileInputStream(aFile);

    FileChannel inChannel = inFile.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);

    while (inChannel.read(buf) != -1) {
      System.out.println("String read: " + ((ByteBuffer) (buf.flip())).asCharBuffer().get(0));
      buf.clear();
    }
    inFile.close();
  }
}
```

output:

```
String read: â¸®
String read: â¸®
String read: â¸®
String read: â¸®
String read: â¸®
String read: â¸®
String read: â¸®
String read: â¸®
String read: â¸®
```

Did you miss anything here?
Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Buffer
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        String inputFile = "charData.xml";
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        FileChannel ch = in.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFSIZE);  // BUFSIZE = 256

        Charset cs = Charset.forName("ASCII"); // Or whatever encoding you want

        /* read the file into a buffer, 256 bytes at a time */
        int rd;
        while ( (rd = ch.read( buf )) != -1 ) {
            buf.rewind();
            System.out.println("String read: ");
            CharBuffer chbuf = cs.decode(buf);
            for ( int i = 0; i < chbuf.length(); i++ ) {
                /* print each character */
                System.out.print(chbuf.get());
            }
            buf.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, thanks! another question: does the bytesize matter here. will be improve performance if I increase it?

Comment: actually, it worked in a sense no more unrecognizable characters, but it's not reading the file line by line

Comment: @DavidZhao But the question was why it is returning junk characters, that I have solved.